# Avoid removing backslashs from file path

Tags: backslash

I have a file path, as string variable:
MyPath="d:\Folder\File.txt,0"
From the beginning I have to say that I can't double the backslashes in this variable, because this variable is read from a text file and in that, it is so.
Now I'd need to get two variables from the Path variable: the path itself (in this case d:\Folder\File.txt) and the index (0, in this case). I wrote a few functions to do this, but each of them are removing the backslashes from the path, I get something like d:FolderFile.txt, which obviously isn't what I'd need.
There is any way to keep the backslashes in the variable?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which language are you writing this in?

Comment: in python: `MyPath = r"d:\Folder\File.txt,0" `

Comment: In C++. But it no longer matters, I solved it.